# No entiendo por que usando la clase BufferedReader no escribe en el fichero

Tags: java

Probando este metodo , no me escribe en el fichero la `i`  y no entiendo el por que ya que el metodo write tiene como parametro un `int`, sin embargo si utilizo `fout.write(""+i)`si lo hace.

```
public void Conversor() throws IOException{
     //recorre las letras del fichero
    int j=0; //corresponde al índice del array de letras
    int i=0;
    char[] arraychar;
    String linea;
    boolean salir=true;

    while((linea = fin.readLine())!=null) {// lee una línea del fichero
        arraychar = linea.toCharArray();
        }

        while(salir) {
            fout.write(i);
            salir=false;
        }
        fout.flush();
        fout.close();



}
```

Clase completa

```
public class Cifrar {

private BufferedWriter fout;
private char secreto[];
private BufferedReader fin;

public Cifrar(Reader rentrada, Writer rsalida) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
   fin=new BufferedReader(rentrada);
   fout=new BufferedWriter(rsalida);
}


public void cCifrador(){
    this.secreto="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ ".toCharArray();
}

public void Conversor() throws IOException{
     //recorre las letras del fichero
    int j=0; //corresponde al índice del array de letras
    int i=0;
    char[] arraychar;
    String linea;
    boolean salir=true;

    while((linea = fin.readLine())!=null) {// lee una línea del fichero
        arraychar = linea.toCharArray();
        }

        while(salir) {
            fout.write((char)i);
            salir=false;
        }
        fout.flush();
        fout.close();



}
```

Comment: ``fout`` es un ``FileOutputStream`` ?

Comment: Te recomiendo mirar estos dos ejemplos de [bufferedReader y bufferedWriter](https://www.boraji.com/java-bufferedreader-and-bufferedwriter-example), como el propio nombre te dice, Buffered**Reader** lee, para escribir tendrás que usar Buffered**Writer**.

Comment: Puse mi clase, completa , estoy usando `bufferedWriter,` pero no funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como indica en la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write(int)) el método `write(int c)` indica que sirve para escribir un determinado caracter, por lo que si quieres escribir un entero deberás convertirlo primero.

```
fout.write(String.valueOf(i));
```

Comment: Gracias ahora si me funciona.